# Use of undefined constant?

Tags: php, curl

I am receiving the following error message:

```
application/libraries/GoogleMapAPI.php [2515]:
Use of undefined constant ‘allow_url_fopen’ - assumed '‘allow_url_fopen’'
```

I am not a coder and am not sure if this is a simple fix or if I need some serious help. Does anyone recognize this problem and if so what are my next steps?

This error follows my adding some code after doing some google research:

```
function fetchURL($url) {
if (ini_get(‘allow_url_fopen’)) {

return file_get_contents($url);

} elseif (function_exists(‘curl_init’)) {

$curlObj = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($curlObj, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$content = curl_exec($curlObj);

curl_close($curlObj);

return $content;

} else {

die(‘Error’);

}

}
```

Any pointers of help very welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's caused by those quotation marks. Change your quotation marks from `‘` to `'`

Comment: Good catch. How did those curly quotes even get in there? Was this code cut and pasted through Word at some point?

Comment: Thanks that has worked! easiest fix ever

Comment: Curly quotes usually come from cut/paste from other applications (MS word + others appear to be the usual cause!)